# How can I delete a string inside parentheses using sed, inside a sed script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I would like to remove text inside parentheses (including the parentheses) using sed **in a sed script**. For example, I would like to delete the phrase (Chris Pratt) and (Chris-Pratt) and keep (Chris_Pratt). (They are both on the same line). And do this for the entire file. For example, the line looks like this:

```
Star Lord (Chris Pratt), (Chris-Pratt), age 42, actor, (Chris_Pratt)
```

This is what I would want to to look like after the sed command in a sed script:

```
Star Lord, age 42, actor, (Chris_Pratt)
```

**That's what I want to do with every single line (there are multiple lines with other names).**

I have already tried:

```
s/[(][^)]*[)]//g
```

This one works, but it also deletes the parentheses **including** the underscore, also:

```
s/\([[:alpha:]]{1,} [[:alpha:] ]{1,}\)\ //g
```

This one does work when I run it with sed normally in the command line, but it doesn't work when I run it in a script for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/ *([^()_]*)//g' file > outputfile
```

Same pattern with POSIX ERE syntax:

```sh
sed -E 's/ *\([^()_]*\)//g' file > outputfile
```

*Details*:

- `*`
- `(` - a literal `(` char (since it is a POSIX BRE pattern), when using POSIX ERE, `\(` must be used
- `[^()_]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `_`
- `)` - a literal `)` char (since it is a POSIX BRE pattern), when using POSIX ERE, `\)` must be used.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/6SSA8Q):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Star Lord (Chris Pratt), age 42, actor, (Chris_Pratt)'
sed 's/ *([^()_]*)//g' <<< "$s"
# => Star Lord, age 42, actor, (Chris_Pratt)
sed -E 's/ *\([^()_]*\)//g' <<< "$s"
# => Star Lord, age 42, actor, (Chris_Pratt)
```

Demo screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hm. When I run this command it deletes all the text in my file and only leaves the parentheses and underscores. Not sure what's happening?

Comment: @JoshuaBorden You are not using my code then.

Comment: I am quite literally using the exact code. What are you talking about?

Comment: @JoshuaBorden If you use `sed 's/ *([^()_]*)//g' file > outputfile`, `outputfile` will have the expected text.

Comment: @JoshuaBorden So, does it work with the POSIX ERE pattern now? You must have `-r` or `-E` option.

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution(`sed` solution):*** With your shown samples, please try following `sed` program. Using `sed`'s backreference capability here.

```
sed -E 's/(^[^(]*) \([^)]*\), \([^)]*\)(.*)/\1\2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed`'s `-E` option which enables ERE(Extended regular expressions) in our program here. Then in main program using `s` option of `sed` to perform substitution operation. We are mentioning `(^[^(]*) \([^)]*\), \([^)]*\)(.*)` which is creating 2 back references here(a temp space in memory to retrieve caught values later in program). While substituting using `\1`(first backreference) and `\2`(2nd back reference) to get the expected output mentioned by OP.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
(^[^(]*)               ##Creating 1st capturing group which captures values from starting of line to till 1st occurrence of ( here.
 \([^)]*\), \([^)]*\)  ##Matching space ( till next occurrence of ) here followed by comma then space followed by ( till next occurrence of ).
(.*)                   ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has everything after previous match.
```

---

---

***2nd solution(`awk` solution):*** Added an `awk` solution here, by using `match` function of `awk`. regex used is same as mentioned above, so simple explanation for this program would be; match not needed part by this function and print only required part.

```
awk '
match($0,/[[:space:]]*\([^)]*\),[[:space:]]*\([^)]*\)/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: So sorry I forgot to mention this! There is also a parentheses with a "-" in it like this "(Earth-16)" I also need to get rid of that too. Your code works perfectly. Is there a way to remove that one with a "-" in it too?

Comment: @JoshuaBorden, sure not an issue, please try following code: `sed -E 's/(^[^(]*) \([^)]*\), \([^)]*\)(.*)/\1\2/' Input_file` once and let me know then how it goes, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/ *\([^()]*\),(.*\(.*\))/\n\1/;ta;s/,*\n+/,/g' file
```

Replace all literals within parens (including the parens) preceded by a possible space and followed by a `,` followed by at least one more literal within parens with a newline.

Then replace multiple newlines preceded by a possible `,`'s with a single `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify if you’re actually using the `-E` option for **“extended” regex**.

With `-E` on, parentheses (`()`) must be escaped (`\(`) to match *literally*. Without escaping, they’re interpreted as group/field separators (without `-E` this is reversed).

My solutions assume `-E` is on.

- For an executable `sed` script your shebang should look similar to `#!/bin/sed -Ef` or `#!/usr/bin/env -Ssed -Ef`
- For a non executable `sed` script, invoke it like: `sed -Ef my-script`

**Solution:**

If the lines all have the same layout, use this:

```
s/([[:space:]]+\([^)]+\),){2}/,/
```

If the layout varies, try on of these:

```
s/[[:space:]]*\([^)]*[- ][^)]+\)//
s/[[:space:]]*\([^)]*[- ][^)]+\),?//g
```

All parenthesised fields *containing* a space and/or dash are removed, also leading whitespace and a trailing comma (if either is present). For the first match only, any comma is preserved.

```
s/[[:space:]]*\([^)_]+\)//
s/[[:space:]]*\([^)_]+\),?//g
```

All parenthesised fields *not* containing an underscore are deleted (including `(Madonna)`). Ditto (as above) with the whitespace and commas.

Edit: I slightly misread your expected output. You would have gotten `Star Lord age 42, actor, (Chris_Pratt)` instead of `Star Lord, age 42, actor, (Chris_Pratt)` (note the first comma). I fixed the solutions accordingly.